# Is there a way to toggle MarkerClustererPlus

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I use MarkerClustererPlus for clustering markers on google map (v3)

Is there a way to toggle clustering with a function.
Namely I dont wont to effect markers, but only toggle visibility of cluster icons.

For showing it we have property - repaint, but I couldnt find the property to hide clusters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set the map-option of the markerClusterer

```
clustererObject.setOptions({map:null});//hides the clusterIcons
clustererObject.setOptions({map:mapObject});//restores the clusterIcons
```

Note: when you set the map to null all clustered markers will appear as markers, I'm not sure if this is the desired behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to just hide all clusters, then Dr. Molle's answer works great. If you're looking to hide just a sub-group/sub-section of your maps markers, then a refresh/rebuild will be needed.

Here's an advanced example that may help others finding this page thru Google Search.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.1/examples/advanced_example.html